# How to update Pulumi state to a new (and non backwards compatible) provider?

Tags: pulumi

I am using the Elastic Cloud Provider (https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/ec/) currently at version 0.4.1 and want to upgrade to 0.6.0. Under the hood this uses Terraform and there are breaking changes in the format of the state JSON between these versions. For example strings becoming booleans, and arrays becoming objects, etc.

I want to keep the current Elastic Cluster deployed and not recreated it. So I want to upgrade the package and upgrade the Pulumi state to match the unchanged cluster but with the state that is compatiable with 0.6.0.

I have tried trying to use `pulumi update` but this uses the old provider to do the update, so nothing happens. I have tried deleting the state of the ec cluster and reimporting, but again same thing. It looks like I need to get the 0.6.0 version of the provider into the state so I can use that for the import, but I have had no luck in getting that to work.

E.g. a command like this to only deploy the provider:

```
pulumi up --target urn:pulumi:lab.eus::xyz-shared::pulumi:providers:ec::default_0_6_0
```

Had no effect, nothing got changed. I was hoping this would work so I could do this:

```
pulumi import ec:index/deployment:Deployment xyz-shared-ec 29ddbe1...bf --provider urn:pulumi:lab.eus::xyz-shared::pulumi:providers:ec::default_0_6_0
```

What is the best way to approach a situation like this where:

1. You have an existing resource you don't want to change or recreated.
2. You want to update the provider for that resource.
3. The resource provider update has breaking changes in it's state format.

Comment: I'd recommend trying their slack channel or creating a GH bug

Comment: I have a way forward @mikus, if it works I might post an answer. I don't think this is a bug per-se. Maybe a shortcoming in the tooling?

Comment: What error does Pulumi show on update when trying to use new provider?

Answer (score 0):

You may try one of these:

---

**Manually update your state to use new provider**

- Create a temporary clone of your Elastic cluster using the new provider in another stack, and compare the generated state between 0.4.1 and 0.6.0. (export states with [`pulumi stack export`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_stack_export/))
- Manually update real stack so that it matches 0.6.0 format (keep a backup of original state). You'll probably need to change the Provider resource itself along the Cluster resource. Use [`pulumi stack import`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_stack_import/)
- Update Elastic provider to 0.6.0 in real stack and refresh / preview to see if it works

---

**Remove  Cluster from state and re-import using new provider**

- Export stack state with [`pulumi stack export`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_stack_export/) and remove Cluster resource, update state with [`pulumi stack import`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_stack_import/) (keep a backup of original state). Your stack will now ignore the Cluster.
- Update to 0.6.0 Provider. This won't change your Cluster since it's not in the state.
- Import your cluster with [`pulumi import`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/cli/commands/pulumi_import/) using new provider, your Cluster should now be managed using 0.6.0 provider